# Sync  Facebook contacts with Gmail contacts

Tags: gmail, facebook, android

On my Android phone, I have my Facebook contacts synched with my Gmail, but not on desktop.

Is it possible to make desktop Gmail sync/import my Facebook contacts? Email, phone, name, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "desktop gmail"?

Comment: @Cawas, sorry, "desktop gmail" equals "gmail on desktop" aka regular gmail thru a web browser vs. gmail on android.

Comment: Yeah, I should have figured - but the whole context got me confused. I don't know how to answer your question, but I do know that *if it were* synched with gmail, it would be on the desktop primarily. So, if you've got your facebook contacts on your android's gmail **it's not through syncing**. It's probably just locally on the android phone, through the OS and not through google.

Comment: Can we try and include a way to sync images or should I start a seperate thread?

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way of getting Facebook contacts to Gmail especially since a spat between Google and Facebook re social graph ownership. There is, however, a **roundabout half-way** of doing it via Yahoo Mail.

Yahoo Mail allows download of Facebook friends' emails. Then, if you can sync up Yahoo and Gmail you'll get to your target.

This second bit also got trickier since the great contacts sync tool **Plaxo** removed scheduled sync of Yahoo accounts... They still allow manual pull of contacts from Yahoo (as well as Facebook, as a matter of fact) but it's not real syncing.

This is the closest you can easily get to in terms of getting your Facebook friends into your Gmail contacts permanently.